# 2-column form condense down to 1-column on smaller devices

Tags: html, css, reactjs, media-queries

My signup form is currently across two columns.

When on a smaller screensize, I would like the two columns to condense down into one column, so that the form field is not too tight trying to fit two input fields across a mobile screen size

How can I adjust my CSS or React/HTML? Below is both the code for my signup page, and the css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding {
  background: #f0f0f0 !important;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Inter';
   -left: 20vw;
  min-width: 100%;
}


h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,


label,
span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'inter';
}

body,
html,
.App,
#root,
.auth-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p{
  font-family: Inter;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 28px;
color: #939599;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #494D61;
  
  }

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.Logo {
  margin-top: 2vh;
}

.auth-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  background:#ffffff;
  margin: 8vw 0;
  position: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.auth-inner {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}


.auth-wrapper .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #FBB381;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.auth-wrapper .form-control {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
border-color: #EBEBEB;

}

.auth-wrapper h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #FBB381;
}

.form-group:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  margin: 5px 0;
}


.form-signup {
  display: grid; /* to use css-grid */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* creates 2 columns */
  gap: 10px 50px; /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
  
}

.form-login {
  display: flex; /* to use css-grid */
  width: 35vw;
  gap: 10px 50px; /* creates a gap between the columns and rows */
 
}


form.form-login .login > div.form-group {
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

form h3,
form h4,
form p,
form button {
  grid-column: span 2; /* lets those elements span both columns */
}

.signup-button {
  grid-column: span 2; /* lets those elements span both columns */
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white
}


.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 75vw;
  /* flexbox is sued to palce the label and input below each other and allows the input to fill out the entrie width */
}


.button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;

}

.login-button {
  background-color: #FBB381;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FBB381;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.sidebar-container{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.sidebar {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.sidebar-link{
  padding: 0px;
}

.sidebar-link:hover{
  border-right: 5px solid #FBB381;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import TopNav from "./TopNav"
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";

export default class SignUp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            
<TopNav />
          </div>
                <div className="auth-wrapper">
                <div className="auth-inner">
            <form className="form-signup">
              
            <h4>Sign Up</h4>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
            </p>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>First name</label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="First name" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Last name</label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Last name" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Email address</label>
              <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" />
            </div>
            <p className="forgot-password text-right">
              Already registered <a href="/sign-in">log in?</a>
            </p>
            <button type="submit" className="signup-button">Sign Up</button>
          
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a job for `@media` queries.

Comment: you can use a media query and just set the grid-template-columns when screens gets that size.

Comment: Please read first about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) try an attempt with it and if you still have question then ask again.